# Duplicate Groups Showing when grouping a calculated column

Tags: 2013, calculated-column, view, grouping

I have recently upgraded our 2007 envrioment to 2013 and afterwards a few of our libraries are having trouble grouping on a calculated column. The year column is calculated using the following formula ( =TEXT([As of Date],"yyyy") ). When a document is added or edited in the library the year group it was in gets duplicated as in the screen shot below. I can fix the issue be re creating the calculated field and fixing the view, however as soon as a document is edited or added it starts all happening again.

Any Ideas?

[image: Grouping Issue]

Comment: i'm having trouble getting the screen shot to show. But basically there are 2 2013 groups and 2 2012 groups in the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After speaking with microsoft the June CU fixes this issue. We have tested on both our dev and QA enviroment and we are rolling it out to PROD this week.

Answer (score 1):

I am seeing the same issue after we just upgraded a customer to 2013.  Pretty much the same issue.  We have a calculation using the LEFT function to get the first letter of a title so that we can group from A-Z.  By opening the calculated column settings and just clicking **OK** it fixes it.  But the problem keeps coming back after anything is edited.  Would love to know if you find a solution.

Comment: glad to see i'm not the only one. It looks like it is happening in all of our site collections where we group on a calculated field.

Comment: which version of sharepoint are your running currently?

Comment: Our customer is on the March CU.  I hesitate to apply a later unless I know it specifically will address this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Same issue. Workaround that worked with me: update all items (or files) of the library. I have done a bulk update easily copying pasting one column to the same column. Now there are no more repeating groups in the list.

Answer (score 0):

Are you on the latest CU?  I have heard a few reports of XSLT not playing nicely in 2013 so this could be another example of that as opposed to an issue with the calculated column.

Comment: We are not, I will look into updating. But Would still like to see if anyone else has had a similar issue and what their resolution was?